# How to gather windows from secondary monitor while remotely connected from OS X to Windows 7

Tags: macos, windows, remote-desktop

I need to gather all of my open applications running on Windows 7 to one screen via remote desktop connection using my Macbook. How can this be achieved? As it is, one program (Notepad ++) is stuck on the second monitor, which I cannot see on my Macbook screen.

My questions is very similar to this form superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/216277/windows7-how-to-gather-windows-from-secondary-monitor

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Connection setting & check 'Scale Content' and 'Use all monitors'.

'Use all monitors' is the key, 'scale content' gives you the choice of scrolling or seeing all at once, but might be too small to read easily.

[image]

Just for completeness… that option isn't directly available on Windows until Windows 8.1 & also on Windows it's called 'Smart Sizing'.
To use Smart Sizing in Windows XP or Windows 7 you need to edit your .rdp files with notepad and type in the following line:

`smart sizing:i:1`